# z-index not working as expected (Chrome and Opera)

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a div with class "opaque" and another with class "product-info", which are both on the same level.

The code is as follows:

```
<div class="opaque"></div>
<div class="product-info">
    <img class="product-image" src="/Images/D3.jpg" />
    fsdfdsfsdfs
</div>
```

```css
.opaque 
{
    background-color: White;
-moz-opacity:.60; filter:alpha(opacity=60); opacity:.60;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: 1;
}

.product-info 
{
padding: 5px;
text-align: center;
z-index: 2;
}
```

Note that product-info is set to z-index 2 and opaque has z-index 1. Therefore product-info should be displayed over opaque so should not be faded. However the image within product-info (and text) is faded. This happens in both Chrome and Opera, therefore I expect this is what should be happening since they are not IE!

There are lots of bits of HTML code as shown above, each nested in lis which are set to float left with width of 33%. When the page is fully loaded (`$(window).load()`) I use jQuery to detect the maximum height of all the products and apply that height to all the rest. I have tried removing all the jQuery in case this is affecting the z-index, but I get the same result only with an untidy look and feel.

I have tried using Google Chromes Inspect Element tool and the elements in question are showing the correct characteristics.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here? I have been trying to solve this for a couple of days now and would like to find out what is going on.

Thank you.

Regards,

Richard

Full code as requested:

I think this is all that is required. I will create a page with just this code in a few minutes, to see if it reproduces the problem.

```
<div id="BodyTag_ContentPanel">
    <div class="overlay-background"></div>
    <div class="scroll-pane">
        <div>
            <ul class="product-list">
                <li class="product">
                    <div class="spacer">
                        <div class="opaque"></div>
                        <div class="product-info">
                            <img class="product-image" src="/Images/D3.jpg" />
                            <div class="enlarge">
                                <div class="image-enlargement">
                                    <span class="close"><img src="/Images/close.jpg" /></span>
                                    <div class="enlargement">
                                        <div class="image-container"><img src="/Images/D3.jpg" /></div>
                                        <div class="product-code"><span class="text-container">D3</span></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-code">D3</div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```css
.product-list 
{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.product 
{
    width: 33%;
    height: 25%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.product .spacer 
{
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 4px solid #C47F50;
    position: relative;
}

.product .opaque 
{
    background-color: White;
    -moz-opacity:.60; filter:alpha(opacity=60); opacity:.60;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.product .product-info 
{
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;
}

.product .product-info .product-image 
{
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    min-width: 150px;
    min-height: 150px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.product .product-code 
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -15px;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: White;
    text-align: center;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 4px solid #C47F50;
    line-height: 20px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.product .image-enlargement 
{
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: White;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 4px solid #C47F50;
    z-index: 103;
}

.product .enlarge
{
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I have found the solution!! I simply added `position: relative;` to `.product-info`. I can't believe I was so stupid as to not try that in the first place! Thanks for both your efforts @Thomas & Lazycommit. @Lazycommit your link came in handy - it confirmed that my code should have been working if it weren't for missing out the `position: relative;`. I noticed that they had set the position attribute for all of the divs in the example - this is what made me try it.

Comment: had the same issue, position: relative solved it... thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is a big theme. U may look [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index/The_stacking_context) page from Firefox developers for better understanding browsers stacking.

Comment: Solved it! See my answer. It was bloomin' obvious! Thanks for your help in any case.

Comment: Oh, the 4th point _"on mobile WebKit and Chrome 22+, position: fixed always creates a new stacking context, even when z-index is auto"_ is my problem, now I think I'll go cry somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the z-index of the item that is supposed to be in the back to a negative number, like -1 :)

Comment: That kind of works - it makes the images appear as expected but the background of the content div appears at full opacity, whereas I want it faded if it is within a product, if you get what I mean. Basically each product has a border, and I would like the background to be faded only if it is within the border, but not the image or the text in the `.product-info` div.

Comment: I think there may be a problem with your HTML, then, according to http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency you cannot change the layering of other elements outside of a transparent object over elements inside of it. What does your HTML look like?

Comment: I'll edit my post so a full product list is there, with the relevant CSS. Give me a few minutes...

Comment: I've added the code now. Please see if you can see anything wrong with it. I have not tested it to make sure it reproduces the problem, but I will do that in the next few minutes.

Comment: Solved it! See my answer. It was bloomin' obvious! Thanks for your help in any case.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but you can use rgba() instead of opacity and get rid of the "product-info" div.  This does the same effect you want since rgba() uses a different method of causing transparency that does not make the children elements go transparent as well.  Makes doing the effect you wanted much easier.

Answer (score 0):

if there is outer div to set `position: fixed;` and you need `position: fixed;` there add `z-index` same as inner div.
ex:

```
.notifications {
    position: fixed;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 70%;  
    z-index: 9999;
}

.notifications > div {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
    /*  margin: 5px 0px;*/ /*default value*/
    margin: 65px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

will work fine.

But if notifications class like below it does not set `z-index` in chrome correctly.

```
.notifications {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 70%;  
    z-index: 9999;
}
```